# size of javascript elements not working properly

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, windows-phone-7, xaml

I have a javascript function that I am using in a WP7 C# application which for some reason is having sizing issues. As of now the function works correctly, but I have three items that are presented as a menubar at the top of my webbrowser control which do not resize according to how I thought I would accomplish this. The sizing part of my function is as follows

Javascript

```
...
pf=doc.createElement('div');
            pf.id='pf';
            var s=pf.style;
            s.position='absolute';
            s.zIndex='999';
            s.top=(scT||scBT)+'px';
            s.left=(scL||scBL)+'px';
            s.width='100%';
            s.height='9%';
            //s.backgroundColor='#FFFF00';
            s.backgroundColor='green';

            //var st = doc.createElement("P");
            //p.style.height='50%';
            //p.style.width='15%';
            //text = doc.createTextNode('Search: ');
            //p.appendChild(text);
            //p.appendChild(doc.createTextNode('Search: '));
            //pf.appendChild(p);
            pf.appendChild(doc.createTextNode('Search: '));

            qt=doc.createElement('input');
            qt.id='qt';                 
            qt.type='text';
            qt.style.height='85%'
            qt.style.width='50%';
            pf.appendChild(qt);

            var sb=doc.createElement('input');              
            sb.type='button';
            sb.value='Find';
            sb.style.height='100%';
            sb.style.width='20%';
...
```

The result of this is a bar loaded on top of the webbrowser page which acts as a Find on Page function. I have sized pf according to the webpage dimensions which works correctly, and I am attempting to make the heights of `pf.appendChild(doc.createTextNode('Search: '));`, `qt=doc.createElement('input');`, and `sb=doc.createElement('input');` match the height of the pf menubar displayed at the top of the page. So far, only the height of sb (set at 100%) matches the height of pf, while setting qt to 100% does not match the height of pf (it changes depending on the height dimension of the currently displayed webpage). Also, I cannot figure out if there is even a way to set the height of pf.appendChild(doc.createTextNode('Search: ')); although what I have tried is commented out above. Is there a way for these to be the same height as the pf menubar at all times? Also, the text is so small on pages with large height dimensions it is unreadable, is there a way to zoom in on the text accordingly as well?

Answer (score 0):

you can try use offsetHeight, if Height property doesn´t work or you can set the Height in the style.Heigth. If you use VS IDE you can debug the javascript element to view the correct property or maybe can set some dummy element with static value.

Comment: Thanks user1031246 I created a dummy element `var fopHeight = .09*myHeight;` giving the same value as the height of the menubar but when attempting to put fopHeight in for `qt.style.height='85%';` and `sb.style.height='100%';` this does not work either. Is this implementation correct? Also, how can I adjust the height of `pf.appendChild(doc.createTextNode('Search: '));` is this allowed in javascript?